# Running script myself outputs one thing and running it from installer outputs other thing

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file

I hope this is not to generic problem, I  currently have a task at work that has a strange behavior. We have an application ( **Installer** ) that run some **bat** files. Nothing strange here. Now we would like to install Sql Server Native in case on the machine it does not exists.

So we created a script that checks where a software is installed or not.

```
param ([Parameter(Mandatory)]$softwareName, $minimumVersion) 

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize
[array]$matchingInstalledSoftware = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -Like $softwareName -and $_.VersionMajor -ge $minimumVersion}

return $matchingInstalledSoftware.Count
```

We are calling it like this from bat file

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File  checkInstalledSoftware.ps1 -softwareName "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client*"'
```

So here comes the problem.

If I run this myself on a VM that has the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client installed it output "1" ( true)

The same bat I am running is ran from our installer ( calls the same exact bat file) but now it outputs "0" (false)

This makes me think is something about the caller of the script, but I have no idea what be? Any ideas?

Comment: when you get different results from two different ways to run code ... the _usual_ cause is the account involved. are you _sure_ that the 2nd way you run things has the same access permissions to the registry key in question?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I am not sure, is there a way I could check it, we are kind of blocked for one day on this one and any input information would be useful to us.

Comment: add some code to get the user account name that the 2nd method uses. then log in _as that account_ to see if the code can run properly.

Comment: we added into the bat file echo %USERNAME% it's the same result ( the bat that runs this ps script)

Comment: i am out of ideas. you will need to carefully try running the code in different ways until you discover the difference ... there is one, but i am lost for ideas on what it could be. [*sigh ...*] ///// good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Make sure that when you run your installer application, you're running it with elevated Administrator permissions. You may need to shift+right-click to get the option to run as admin